# Arduino PulseIn

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I want to print the frequency. I am giving output from one pin and reading the same from next pin by connecting both the pin. I don't understand why the `pulseIn` gives 0 everytime. Here is my code:

```
void loop() {
    unsigned long duration;
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin,HIGH);
    Serial.println(duration);
}
```

Comment: You realise that the delays are blocking right? The pulse has been and gone by the time you call pulseIn...

Comment: Since void loop function keeps on looping, i guess it should read in the next loop but it does not. How can i implement it?

Comment: ```pulseIn``` is blocking too. It sits in a busy loop until it detect the pulse - or returns 0 if no pulse occurs in time.

Comment: Is there anyway i can solve this case and read the frequency?

Comment: Yes, use something else to generate a pulse train. A function generator perhaps, or another Arduino. Or set up PWM, PWM is non-blocking because it uses the hardware timers.